# How to display Character in table cell in Gujarati in PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Hello I am try to display text in Gujarati fonts in pdf using itextsharp

- when I add direct using doc.add(new Phrase("This is a test નમસ્તે નમસ્તે નમસ્તે", f)) its works
- but when I am using pdfpcell means add this in table cell like 
  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(12,"Harikesh નમસ્તે", f));
  its not working (its display blank)

you find total code below I post that..

Kindly help for solve this problem

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
document.SetMargins(88f, 88f, 80f, 30f);
using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
    Phrase phrase = null;
    PdfPCell cell = null;
    PdfPTable maintable = null;
    PdfPTable table = null;
    PdfPTable secondTable = null;
    PdfPCell TableCell = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell secondTableCell = new PdfPCell();
    secondTableCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                            iTextSharp.text.Color color = null;
    document.Open();
    string ARIALUNI_TFF = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    Font f = new Font(bf, 12, Font.NORMAL);
    table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.TotalWidth = 500f;
    table.LockedWidth = true;
    table.SetWidths(new float[] { 10f });
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(12,"Harikesh નમસ્તે", f));
    cell.BorderColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(229, 229, 229);
    cell.FixedHeight = 10f;
    table.AddCell(cell);                       
    document.Add(table);
    document.Add(new Phrase("This is a test નમસ્તે નમસ્તે નમસ્તે", f));
    filename = filename + now.Hour.ToString("00") + now.Minute.ToString("00") + now.Second.ToString("00") + now.Millisecond.ToString() + now.DayOfYear.ToString("000") + now.Day.ToString("00") + now.Month.ToString("00") + now.Year.ToString("0000") + ".pdf";
    document.Close();
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");                      
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
    Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a default font?

Comment: ya i had try with default font like Arial Unicode MS,Arial and it work but now if my record comes in gujarati font than it display blank ... when debug that i show that added in cell but not display in pdf

Comment: have you tried with BaseFont.EMBEBED?

Comment: yes i had try to replace BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED to BaseFont.EMBEBED but still same problem find

Comment: can you able to post any code using table cell for different lang ..

Comment: I supose you have tried to increase FixedHeight

Comment: Thank you so much its work now ....what i do i just remove fixed-height so it take auto height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a font of 12:

```
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(12,"Harikesh નમસ્તે", f));
```

with a fixed height of 10f:

```
cell.FixedHeight = 10f;
```

You can try either to raise the FixedHeight or set it to 0 and let it to use the default height for this font.

Comment: ya i fixed this auto Height ...but at last thank you so much for all @mcNets

Comment: hey Is there any fonts family for all like English,Gujarati,Hindi etc @mcNets bcz i am only getting English and Gujarati no Hindi fonts in pdf any idea

Answer (score 0):

Use followoing code snippet for Gujarati font print into PDF.

```
string ARIALUNI_TFF = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Font/GopikaTwo.ttf");
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

iTextSharp.text.Font font = null;
font = FontFactory.GetFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);


Paragraph GujPara = new Paragraph(new Chunk(gujText, font));

doc.Add(GujPara);
```